# Declaring any vs explicit type in Typescript which one has better perfomance

Tags: typescript

I am searching for some clear explanation on working with `any` declaration vs explicit type for example:

```js
let a: any; 
// versus
let a: modelclassname;
// versus
let a: number;
```

Do they have any performance difference in the compiler and which one has a better handling cost? Any links also will be helpful.

Comment: There should not be any difference, and if there is, it should be so minimal that it does not matter. What you should be doing is avoiding `any`, as it contributes to the readability of your code.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, it is a fairly reasonable question.

Answer (score 2):

There's not difference in performance (at runtime). There may be a slight performance overhead during  static type-checking (at compile time) since, if you declare an explicit type, TypeScript will check that you value it's compatible with it (which takes a bit of effort).

Using `any` is highly discouraged since it has an impact on the readability of your code and makes TypeScript type-checking useless.